# Why can't my Perl object find its skip() method, even though I can call it as a subroutine?

Tags: perl, perl-module, xs

I'm working on a Perl module and whenever I call the `skip()` method I wrote in the following way:

```
$cursor->skip(4);
```

I get:

```
Undefined subroutine &MyModule::Cursor::skip called at t/tester.pl line 24.
        (in cleanup) invalid object at t/tester.pl line 24.
```

When I call it like:

```
MyModule::Cursor::skip($cursor, 4);
```

Perl finds it!

Oddly, if I name "`skip`" anything else ("`skipper`", "`hello`"), this syntax works:

```
$cursor->skipper(4);
```

I thought maybe `skip()` was a "secret" reserved key word or something, but I've also got methods named `sort()` and `next()` (which I know are reserved), and those work fine.

I'd really like to name this method "`skip`."  Does anyone know why Perl can't find it?

Comment: Can you show us a complete, but short, example that illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`skip()` is exported from [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test::More), which you might have loaded since your executable is named `t/tester.pl`.

What does `ref($cursor)` yield you? It should be a blessed `MyModule::Cursor` object, but the "`invalid object`" error might be suggesting the object was not constructed properly.

EDIT: [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html) gives another clue: "`in cleanup`" signifies that a problem was encountered by the object's destructor.  Assuming you don't already have a destructor in the object, create a `MyModule::Cursor::DESTROY` method that `Data::Dump`s the object to see what it looks like at this time.

A concise snippet of example code that exhibits this behaviour would be very helpful.

Comment: The error message says it's looking for *skip* on *MyModule::Cursor*, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: `MyModule::Cursor::skip` may be `Test::More`'s skip though.. although I do find it odd that it can't find *anything*. It would seem that at worst it is finding the wrong version of `skip()`, rather than nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

Without actual code, it's difficult to debug this.

Do you **use MyModule::Cursor** in your test code? When you replaced **skip** with **skipper**, were you calling it in exactly the same way from your test module? Are you able to use **skip** from a throw-away (one-liner or very short script)?

Where I'm going with this is looking for an error in your test code, rather than the module.

**UPDATE:** You're not doing something like declaring methods on **MyModule::Cursor** in two different files, are you? The error message you're getting tells me it has a blessed reference to an object of type **MyModule::Cursor**, so it knows about the class; but then it can't find the definition of **skip**. Do you happen to declare part of **MyModule::Cursor** in one file, and **skip** in another, and your test module isn't including the second file? Or do you have a syntax error somewhere around your definition of **skip** -- a missing semi-colon or unpaired curly brace? (But then again, why would **MyModule::Cursor::skip** work where **$cursor->skip** does not?)